# Ground Handoff to Tower

Tags: air-traffic-control

When a plane is passed from the ground to the tower, do the ground controllers have to give the tower frequency? For example, "N123B Contact Tower on 121.32" rather than "N123B Contact Tower"

Answer (score 2):

According the the [FAA Order 7110.65Z (U.S. Air Traffic Control Handbook)](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/7110.65Z_ATC_Bsc_dtd_6-17-21.pdf), Radio Communications, paragraph 2-1-17 b. 2. (c) Terminal ***(pertinent part)***:

2−1−17. RADIO COMMUNICATIONS

> a. Transfer radio communications before an
> aircraft enters the receiving controller’s area of
> jurisdiction unless otherwise coordinated or specified
> by a letter of agreement or a facility directive.

> **b. Transfer radio communications by specifying
> the following:**

> > 2. Frequency to use except the following may be
> >    omitted:

> > > > (c) TERMINAL:

> > > > > (1) Ground or **local control frequency** if in
> > > > > your opinion the pilot knows which frequency is in
> > > > > use.

EXAMPLE−

> **“Contact Tower.”**

*(emphasis mine)*

Also note that the [Aeronautical Information Manual (AIM),](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/aim_bsc_w_chg_1_2_and_3_dtd_11-03-22.pdf) in paragraph **4-3-14. Communications,** states the following with respect to contacting the Tower (local controller):

**4−3−14. Communications**

> a. Pilots of departing aircraft should communicate
> with the control tower on the appropriate ground
> control/clearance delivery frequency prior to starting
> engines to receive engine start time, taxi and/or
> clearance information. **Unless otherwise advised by
> the tower, remain on that frequency during taxiing
> and runup, then change to local control frequency
> when ready to request takeoff clearance.**

> ***NOTE−***
> *Pilots are encouraged to monitor the local tower frequency
> as soon as practical consistent with other ATC
> requirements.*
>
> ***REFERENCE−***
> *AIM, Paragraph 4−1−13 , Automatic Terminal Information Service
> (ATIS)*

> b. The tower controller will consider that pilots of
> turbine−powered aircraft are ready for takeoff when
> they reach the runway or warm−up block unless
> advised otherwise.

*(emphasis mine)*

So, as noted in the AIM guidance above, if you are ready to request your takeoff clearance and have not yet received instructions from the ground controller to "Contact Tower" or "Contact Tower on (some frequency)" you should change to the local control frequency.

Answer (score 0):

At the towered airports I fly out of, typically class D and C here in the US there is no explicit handoff to tower but rather you call the tower when you get to the hold short line. The sequence from the ramp goes:

> N123AB: Ground, N123AB at the ramp with the weather requesting taxi to the active runway

> Ground: N123AB taxi to Runway 26 via romeo alpha

> N123AB: Taxi runway 26 via romeo alpha

Then when your at the hold short line you tune your radio to tower

> N123AB: Tower, N123AB is holding short Runway 26 at alpha

> Tower: N123AB cleared for takeoff runway 26

- "the weather" [is identified by an alphabetic designator that rotates](https://airplaneacademy.com/the-difference-between-atis-awos-and-asos/#:%7E:text=ATIS%20contains%20current%2C%20routine%20information,continuous%20real%2Dtime%20weather%20observations.) so for example might be "with echo"
- There is typically one tower frequency which is why a frequency is often not given but at large airports like KJFK which has multiple tower frequencies [depending on the runway you are taxing to](http://www.airnav.com/airport/jfk)
- Small class D airports, during non busy times, may have the tower controller also working ground but a frequency change is still required on departure. In my experience on landing the tower will sometimes issue *"taxi to the ramp via romeo alpha with me"* indicating not to call ground to get your taxi instructions.

[This question is also related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/51409/when-to-switch-from-ground-to-tower-frequencies-at-controlled-airports-in-the-us)